# Java - Give certain bitpattern positions, a certain value

Tags: java, position

If you have an integer-variable named i, that contains a bitpattern...

How can you make a Java-structure that gives every bit that's in an odd position, 1 as value?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? it is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: For example: You have a bitpattern like this: "00011001" I now want a Java-structure that converts every bit at an odd position to value 1, which would lead to: "01011101"

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 32; x+=2) {
    i |= 1 << x;
}
```

or even:

```
i |= 0x55555555;
```

Comment: I'm only supposed to use bitwise logic operators

Comment: The second example uses only that, it's just like: `i = i | 0x55555555;`

Comment: Thx for this. I get that 0x5555555 give a 0101010101 like binary pattern. What I don't get is how you select the odd bits in the original pattern to be converted to 1? (I'm completely new @ java...)

Comment: `1 << x` shifts 1 `x` bits to the left, i.e. `1 << 4` == `00000...00001 << 4` == `00000...10000`, then, ORing the result with `i` we set this bit on in `i`, so we do for any second position.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a similar method like this to set or unset bits:

```
public static int setBitOnInt(int i, int bit, boolean set) {
    if (set) {
        return i | (1 << bit);
    } else {
        return i & ~(1 << bit);
    }
}
```

To set only odd bits you'd have to call:

```
int myBitMask = 0;
for (int i=0; i<32; i+=2) {
    myBitMask = setBitOnInt(myBitMask, i, true);
}
```